# how to count number of id using multiple filter

Tags: c#, mysql, group-by, linq-to-entities

**TableA**

```
TableAId profile  prof_type  groupId   division     Department     unitBranch
 1        prof1     1           1          1            1              1
 2        prof2     2           1          1            1              1
 3        prof3     1           2          1            3              1
 4        prof4     1           1          1            3              1
```

**TableB**

```
TableBId   staff          groupId   division     Department     unitBranch
  1         ali            1          1            1              1
  2         Mohammad       2          1            1              1              
  3         ahmad          1          1            3              1
  4         omar           1          1            3              1
  5         othman         1          1            1              1
  6         basam          1          1            3              1
  7         saaed          3          1            3              1
```

I am trying to create list like

```
groupId   division     Department     unitBranch     COUNT
     1          1            1              1          2
     2          1            3              1          1
     1          1            3              1          3
```

This is the query which I am trying to create but I am getting wrong results.

```
var tes = (from a in db.TableA
                       join b in db.TableB on a.GroupID equals b.GroupID //here need to filter multiple value (group,department,divsion ,unit)
                       group b by a into g
                       select new
                       {

                       });
```

Please Help to write query return count of staff where (groupID ,division ,department , unitbranch) in tableA = Table B .

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article on using composite keys:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/join-by-using-composite-keys
You should be able to use the `new` statement.
The `group` statement below may need tweaked once you run real data through it.

```
    var tes = (from a in db.TableA
               join b in db.TableB
               on new { a.GroupID, a.division, a.Department, a.unitbranch } equals new { b.GroupID, b.division, b.Department, b.unitbranch } into joinedValues
               group joinedValues by a into g
               select g);
```

Comment: thanks for help me , but now how can count total record have same groupID ,divivson , unit and department  ..?

Comment: That's a new question, please accept upvote and accept the answer I posted above to your original question.